# glmnet for R under windows

Tags: r, windows, glmnet

stats experts,

I want to install glmnet to learn from the examples of Jared Lander's R for everyone (2nd ed).
I am running R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) under Rstudio on a Windows machine. When I try to install glmnet I receive the message 'glmnet’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1). I've seen an older discussion on this topic but not a recent thread. My question is: will this package likely become available in the near future under Windows and what alternative(s) - if any- do you recommend?

Kind regards,
Rob

Comment: The current version of R is 3.6.1. Update R and try again.

Comment: If you need to run it under R 3.5 bultd it yourself from source.  I have it running under R 3.5 on Windows using  glmnet 2.0.18 and on R 3.6 on Windows using glmnet 3.0.1.

Comment: The current version of glmnet depends on R (≥ 3.6.0) and Matrix (≥ 1.0-6). Thus it won't ever be available to 3.5.1. You need to upgrade. On windows, I'd use `installr::updater()`.

Comment: Thanks folks, this really helps!